# Which kind of lawyer does a hacking and spying victim need?

Tags: internet, hacking, phone

In the event that someone hacks your devices in order to let people on the internet spy on you every day, which kind of lawyer do you need to attack the situation? Based on what's being done and how it's being done this seems like malicious behavior and harassment more than anything else. This is a personal case, not a corporate one.

I had evidence of spying and during his investigation my hacking forensics guy found many IP addresses of mysterious persons (hackers, criminals) who are all connected to my phone in some highly technical "secret" way. As I research the subject more it looks like law enforcement prefers to point all hacking victims toward the nearest door, so what kind of lawyer am I looking for? I don't want to ignore the situation or replace my devices.

Region: USA

Comment: Do you know who the perpetrators are? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Regardless, I would strongly recommend getting advice from [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over dealing with your compromised device.

Comment: Finding cyber criminals can be very hard, prosecuting them might be even harder. Unless it is a very serious crime, the police won't investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said, it sounds like this isn't a job for a lawyer.

If you are a victim of a crime, you can report it to the police. You don't need a lawyer for that and there's little one could do here. Depending on the location of the perpetrators, this could be reported to local law, or at a national level if they are located in another state. https://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx is the site for reporting online crime.

If you want to sue the perpetrators for damages, you would need a litigation attorney or trial lawyer. Ideally you would want one who specialises in IT related cases. You would need to know who's doing this though- [you can't have a civil case without a defendant](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55159/can-a-question-of-law-be-taken-to-a-civil-court-while-not-naming-a-specific-def/55161#55161).

Answer (score 0):

Internet law, person injury, cyber harassment and protection orders are phrases that can yield leads, thanks to Google. Not so much taxes, corporate mergers, real estate, family law or immigration. The theory is that you will sue the person for the harm that they have done to you. Filing a criminal complaint (with the police) is the first step (ask your lawyer). Lawyer's don't usually investigate who the criminal is, Perry Mason notwithstanding, so in order to sue someone, you have to know who to sue.