# What happens after bugs are found in a private residence?

Tags: hacking, trespass, harassment, hidden

I have evidence of being spied on by complete nobodies and weirdly threatened malicious people on the web so I have a bug sweep coming up. What should I do after the technician finds hidden cameras and audio devices in my home, especially in "forbidden" areas like private bedrooms and bathrooms? Obviously I want to investigate even further and get to the point where one can press charges. What kind of lawyer do I need and what exactly should I say to lazy and uninterested law enforcement?

Comment: where are you? In germany that's a different thing than in Bangladesh or Texas.

Comment: The first call should be to the authorities (police), they can investigate, arrest, and charge.

Comment: And here I thought this was going to be a question about termites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which kind of lawyer does a hacking and spying victim need?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56328/which-kind-of-lawyer-does-a-hacking-and-spying-victim-need)

Answer (score 1):

Until somebody figures out who put the bugs in the house in a way that can be proven, you can't do much other than to document the situation and investigate.

The police might investigate, but might not, in their discretion. The technical details of the evidence discovered would dictate the next step in the investigation.

Hiring a lawyer would not be very helpful until you have someone you can identify to seek to sue or prosecute if it seems sensible at the time. Even if you could identify them and you did sue them, it would be hard to assign significant money damages to the case, there wouldn't ordinarily be a right to your attorney fees if you prevail in a lawsuit, and if you'd already removed the bugs, there might not be much conduct to address with an injunction.

You could consider seeking a restraining order against them, but unless you can prove that these particular people who are bugging you broke into your house, and can do so very quickly and efficiently in ten or twenty minutes of a presentation to a judge, it will be very hard to get such an order. Getting an order also depends upon the nature of the alleged threat.